# Transfer response from remote server to content script (Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What I want to achieve:
Upon clicking icon of my Chrome extension, a file with downloaded from remote location and the user is presented with saveAs dialog.

Caveats: I'm using latest manifest from Google, namely `v3`.

**I have edited this post many times as I I was able to achieve more and more. I leave only my latest code.**

*tl;dr* Now almost everything works.Crucial thing is missing: response from server (body) is not saved. Instead string `[object Object]` is saved.

```
// when icon is clicked
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  if (tab.url.startsWith('http')) {
    post({url: tab.url})
    .then(async res => ({
      filename: getFilename(res.headers.get('Content-Disposition')),
      blob: await res.blob()
    }))
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        func: saveFile,
        args: [response.filename, response.blob],
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      func: showAlert,
      args: [error],
    }));
  }
});

function getFilename(header) {
  return /filename="(.+)"/.exec(header)[1];
}

async function post(data = {}) {
    return await fetch('http://localhost:5000/citation',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: new URLSearchParams(data)
    });
}

function showAlert(error) {
    let message = error.error !== null ? error.error : error.message;
    alert("Error: " + message);
}

async function saveFile(filename, blob) {
  let link = document.createElement('a');

  let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob],
      {type: 'application/octet-stream'}));
  link.href = url;
  link.download = filename;
  link.click();

  // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL.
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 250);
}
```

Comment: I make an extension that dynamically generates a blob then downloads it. I have not gotten it to reliably work with the <a> click behavior in the past. There are two ways I _know_ work reliably: downloading the blob as is (cannot change filename) or asking download permission then using chrome API (had to do this on FF). Are you set on this dynamic <a> strategy?

Comment: @Neea Sure, please share your your solution.

Comment: @menteith does my answer solve your issue with the file content?

Comment: Dear @AhmedHany Thanks for this. As soon as I get back home, I will check this out and let you know.

Comment: It does the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in serializing the `blob` object from the chrome extension to the content script, which I think it's a bug in chrome. if you try to log the blob object that `saveFile()` receives, you will notice it's an empty object.

So instead of passing the `blob` object, you have to pass another serializable object to the content script.

I have converted the `blob` object to a `base64` object then passed it to the content script.

First, let's create a function to convert the `blob` object to a `base64` object

```
function blobToBase64(blob) {
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
}
```

Then convert the `blob` object

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  if (tab.url.startsWith('http')) {
    post({url: tab.url})
    .then(async res => ({
      filename: getFilename(res.headers.get('Content-Disposition')),
      blob: await res.blob()
    }))
    .then(async response => {
      var base64 = await blobToBase64(response.blob)
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        func: saveFile,
        args: [response.filename, base64],
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      func: showAlert,
      args: [error],
    }));
  }
});
```

then in the `saveFile()` method, you need to convert that `base64` into a file

```
async function saveFile(filename, base64URL) {
    fetch(base64URL)
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            let link = document.createElement('a');

            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob],
                { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));
            link.href = url;
            link.download = filename;
            link.click();

            // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL.
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }, 250);
        })
}
```

If you will not do anything in `saveFile()` but download the file, then it will be better to download the file from the extension itself because converting the `blob` to `base64` then getting it back to `blob` again is slowing down the downloading process.